# How to migrate a redis instance to n instance?

Tags: redis, cluster-computing, migrate

I have one redis node already, now the momery is cost much and i want to migrate this to more instance. if i load the rdb in every instance, it must be waste a lot.
I can use "keys " to get all key, and then sharding the data by performing a consistent hash upon the key, but it is very ugly...Any beatiful solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had redis running in with AOF configured you could simply write a script that reads the AOF. That's what we did. With redis in RDB configuration i don't think you can do that.

If you're running redis 2.6 you could use the migrate command:

http://redis.io/commands/migrate

You would still need to iterate over the keys with `KEYS`.

I don't think there is a better solution that iterating over all keys with `KEYS` and then consistently hash them.

If you're not afraid of communicating with redis directly you could process the bulk reply of `KEYS *` while reading it, to speed things up and save memory.

Comment: I've tried in aof and rdb both. All of it works well.Finally i choose aof because it can be done in increase mode.